# Where JavaScript variable is located?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and this seems very strange for me...

```
function Employee() {}
var emp = new Employee();
emp.name = "John Doe";
alert(emp.name);
```

I don't even know what keyword to search about this
Where will, the "name" variable, be located?
global namespace, public property, or whatever?

Comment: I think *public instance property* best sums it up. What is your actual question?

Comment: It's not a variable. It's a property on the `emp` object. An object is a collection of key/value pairs, where the keys are ultimately strings, and the values are of any type. So in your case, the key is `name`, and the value is `"John Doe"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got a couple things going on here that can easily trip up someone new to Javascript. Let's breakdown the script line by line.

```
function Employee() {}
```

This is defining a new constructor function that will create `Employee` objects. Currently, the function does very little.

```
var emp = new Employee();
```

Here, we instantiate an Employee object with the `new` keyword and assign it to the variable `emp`. It will be contained within whatever scope it is declared--in this case, the global scope.

```
emp.name = "John Doe";
```

We set the property `name` of the local object `emp` to be "John Doe." This might seem strange if you're coming from a language that requires you to be more explicit about objects. Javascript doesn't care that the "name" property was never mentioned in your constructor object. So, it's totally cool to assign the "name" property on `emp`. One downside to this is that if you make other instances of `Employee` they won't necessarily have a `name` property.

```
alert(emp.name);
```

Use the browser's alert function to show us the name "John Doe."

So, to answer explicitly, `name` is a "public" property of `emp` (an instance of Employee), in the sense that other people can read/write it directly. Javascript doesn't have a way of explicitly declaring things public or private. To get that kind of behavior, you have to rely on design patterns. If you want to mimic public/private properties, you might consider the "Revealing" pattern, which Addy Osmani lays out in his really great book [Learning Javascript Design Patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript)

Comment: Actually, 'name' is a property of the object reference in `emp` and won't be part of any other instances of `Employee()` unless it is also assigned to them.

Comment: @jfriend00 - clarified.

Comment: Whoa! nice explanation. Thanks for the great answer! And thanks to @jfiend00 too!